# Proving a number is Carmichael

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

here is my question:

Let $p>3$ be prime, s.t $q = 2p-1$ and $g = 3p-2$ are primes as well. (For example $p=19$,$13$,$7$). Prove that $N = pqg$ satisfies $p-1|N-1$, $q-1|N-1$ and $g-1|N-1$.

I tried showing that $N$ is a Carmichael number by proving that for all $b$:
$b^{N-1} \equiv 1 \mbox{ (mod N)}$, or that $\phi(N)|N-1$, but failed on both accounts. Any tips will be appreciated (as well as straight up solutions).

Thank you!

Comment: A prime greater than $3$, when divided by $6$, either leaves a remainder of $1$ or $5$.

Comment: Hmm thanks, so this gives me that 6|N-1, but phi(N) = 6(p-1)^3 and i cant seem to make (p-1)^3 divide N-1 :/

Comment: I don't think you need to show that $N$ is a Carmichael number at all

Comment: @KennyLau You're right, as my answer shows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the fact that we have the following equivalences: $$p-1\mid pqg-1\iff p-1\mid qg-1$$

$$q-1\mid pqg-1\iff q-1\mid pg-1$$

$$g-1\mid pqg-1\iff g-1\mid pq-1$$

If $p>3$ is prime, $q=2p-1$ and $g=3p-2$ are also primes, then $3q=2g+1$.

$q-1=2(p-1)$, so $2(p-1)\mid q-1$ and $q-1\mid 2(p-1)$.

Also $g-1=3(p-1)$, so $g-1\mid 3(p-1)$.

Also $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$, because if $p\equiv -1\pmod{3}$, then $q\equiv 2p-1\equiv 0\pmod{3}$, so $q=3$, contradiction, because $q=2p-1>2\cdot 3-1=5>3$.

$$2(p-1)\mid q(3q-1)-2$$

$$=3q^2-q-2=(3q+2)(q-1)$$

is true because $2(p-1)\mid q-1$.

$$q-1\mid p(3p-2)-1$$

$$=3p^2-2p-1=(3p+1)(p-1)$$

is true because $p$ is odd, so $3p+1$ is even, so $$q-1\mid 2(p-1)\mid (3p+1)(p-1)$$

$$g-1\mid p(2p-1)-1$$

$$=2p^2-p-1=(2p+1)(p-1)$$ is true because $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$, so we get $3\mid 2p+1$, so $$g-1\mid 3(p-1)\mid (2p+1)(p-1)$$

Comment: Thank you! That does it :)